# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `event_title' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

UPDATE:
Thank you for the help. I've been able to track this issue back to the fact that the "order" action in the Tickets controller is not firing. This would explain the error and as some of you pointed out, the @event is basically nil.

My routes are as follows:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do       

      get 'tickets', to: 'tickets#index'
      post 'order', to: 'tickets#order'
      post 'confirmation', to: 'tickets#confirmation'
```

I've updated the Index.html.erb page to use form_tag instead since I'm not modifying an object, but simply wanting to send parameters to the order action.

```
<%= form_tag order_path do %>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">Choose Your Tickets:
         <%= collection_select(:tickets, :ticket_id, Tickettype.where(event_id:    event.id) , :id, :ticketname) %>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="<%= event.id %>" name="event_id" />
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns">Quantity:
      <%= select_tag(:ticketqty, options_for_select(["-----Select Quantity-----", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]))%>
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 columns">
      <%= submit_tag "Purchase tickets", class: "alert button" %>
      </div>
     </div>
   <% end %>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

---

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past several hours and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Very simply, I have a form on my index page that passes params to the "order" page. Using  <%= params.inspect %> I can see everything showing up as expected on the "order" page. My issue arises when I attempt to use them in my controller code.

```
def order
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @tickets = Tickettype.find(params[:tickets][:ticket_id])
end
```

I then try to reference the event I'm looking up on my "order" page using

```
<%= @event.event_title %>
```

but it keeps throwing the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `event_title' for nil:NilClass):
    10:   <div class="large-12 columns">
    11:     <%= params.inspect %>
    12:   
    13:   <%= @event.event_title %>
    14:   <%= params[:ticketqty] %>
    15:     
    16:         </div>
  app/views/tickets/order.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_tickets_order_html_erb___998894167849228569_70303636962040'
```

Using the rails console, I've confirmed that I can create an event object and then display it's title

```
@event = Event.find(16)
@event.event_title
```

This prints out the expected title. Needless to say I'm stuck as to why I can create the object from the console, but it doesn't seem to work from within my controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full code of my Tickets Controller:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # return next 4 upcoming events
    @events = Event.order(event_datetime: :desc).limit(4)

  end

  def order
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @tickets = Tickettype.find(params[:tickets][:ticket_id])

  end
end
```

And here is my routes file:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do


  get 'tickets', to: 'tickets#index'
  post 'order', to: 'tickets#order'
  post 'confirmation', to: 'tickets#confirmation'
```

This is the code from the index page that is passing the parameters to the order.html.erb file.
INDEX.HTML.ERB

```
<%= form_for :tickets, :url => { :controller => "tickets", :action => "order" }, html: {method: "post"} do |f| %>
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-6 columns">Choose Your Tickets:
      <%= f.collection_select(:ticket_id, Tickettype.where(event_id: event.id) , :id, :ticketname) %>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="<%= event.id %>" name="event_id" />
    </div>
    </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="large-6 columns">Quantity:
                   <%= select_tag(:ticketqty, options_for_select(["-----Select Quantity-----", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]))%>
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 columns">
                  <%= f.submit "Purchase tickets", class: "alert button" %>
                </div>
              </div>
                <% end %>
```

And this is ORDER.HTML.ERB

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <P></P>
    <h4 class="page_header">Order Details</h4>
    <span class="areatitle-line"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <%= params.inspect %>


    <%= @event.event_title %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is an example output of the parameters that I see posted to the Order.html.erb page.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nLEehsQWzrkjXmtX0qEFpkHXGkEMGX3NV6tLjb2HRFAKwwdGtxM028dpclMjukmGIuD4XJk+OTAhw4L9norZPg==", "tickets"=>{"ticket_id"=>"4"}, "event_id"=>"17", "ticketqty"=>"2", "commit"=>"Purchase tickets", "controller"=>"tickets", "action"=>"order"}
```

Comment: Could you paste the full content of your tickets_controller and your routes?

Comment: I updated the post to include this info. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens when you define @event in your index action in the tickets controller

Comment: The Index page loads fine and populates the form as desired. I'm very confused on why similar logic works on the Index page, but not the Order page.

Answer (score 1):

In controller you did not create a object, but trying to find a event record using activerecord.

ActiveRecord creates a model object using the record values if the record is found.

If it cannot find the record it will return nil.

My first suggestion for you will be to use

```
    find_by(id: params[:event_id])
```

rather than find as find_by will give nil if record not found but find will through an record not found exception.

So to escape from the error you are facing in view, first check a condition whether an event is nil or not and show event details only if @event object is not nil.

```
     <%= if !@event.nil? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several places on your order.html.erb you seem to reference event as a local variable and not as an instance variable as you defined it in the controller.  Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `event_id` in the form, as post parameter.

Therefore, it makes perfect sense to expect `params[:event_id]` to be null.

Instead, you should use the parameter **from the form**:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:tickets][:event_id])
```

Having said that, I would expect an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception... That is, before getting a nil object....